# How to save skins in Corona SDK?

Tags: coronasdk

I do my game and I have one problem. In my game will be skins. And player can choose them. How can I save skins(images)? How can player choose them? What do I need to do? Use JSON or SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

Add Preference to your images,like you have two themes blue and red.put your images in assert blue_BG.jpg and red_BG.jpg.if user selected the blue theme.see the below code:

```
 local selectedTheme = "blue"

 local Background=display.newImage(sceneGroup,selectedTheme.."_BG.jpg",320,480)
```

Comment: If you got the solution from my answer accept my answer.